# Unable to update binded control in Silverlight view

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

XAML code:

```
                <TextBlock Text="Country" Foreground="white" TextAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"  />
                <TextBox 
                    x:Name="txtCountries"
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Margin="2, 2, 2, 2"
                    Text="{Binding PhysicalDeliveryParameters.Countries, Converter={StaticResource EnumerableToTextConverter}, ConverterParameter='...'}"
                    IsReadOnly="True">
                </TextBox>
                <Button
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Grid.Column="3"
                    Content="..."
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Tag="Countries"
                    Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" />
```

C# code :

```
    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PhysicalDeliveryParametersViewModel pvm = GetViewModel();
        GenericObservableCollection<SelectableItem> items = pvm.Countries; 

        PhysicalDeliveryParametersDlg dlg = new PhysicalDeliveryParametersDlg(items);
        dlg.Closed += (o, args) =>
            {
                BindingExpression binding = txtCountries.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
                if(null != binding)
                    binding.UpdateSource();
            };

        dlg.ShowDialog();
    }
```

When I click on the button, the ButtonBase_OnClick() method executes : a dialog appears (PhysicalDeliveryParametersDlg class) and I choose some values. The binded data (PhysicalDeliveryParameters.Countries, which is an ObservableCollection) is updated, but not the Text property of my TextBox... Did I do something wrong ?

PS : I'm not sure I use the best method to create a modal window in Silverlight, could you give me some advice ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is that `PropertyChanged` never gets raised on the "Countries" property, so the view doesn't know it needs to update.  (Actually, it probably wouldn't help to raise "PropertyChanged" in this case -- since the object reference has not changed, I believe the runtime would ignore it.)

I would just add another property "CountriesString" or similar:

```
Text="{Binding PhysicalDeliveryParameters.CountriesString}"
```

Update the property whenever is appropriate:

```
dlg.Closed += (o, args) =>
{
    pvm.CountriesString = string.Join(", ", pvm.Countries);
};
```

Comment: This is the solution I will use. But I hoped to have a better/cleaner one :-(

Comment: @schglurps what seems bad/unclean about it?  Just the fact that it updates the countries string manually, instead of using a binding?